# Conditions for functions to be independent of one of their variables

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm working independently through Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and I've come across a stumbling block with respect to two of his questions.

The first question is

**2.22**.  If $f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ and $D_2f=0$, show that $f$ is independent of the second variable.

$D_2f$ is the second partial derivative of $f$, defined by $$D_2f =\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a^1,a^2+h)-f(a^1,a^2)}{h}$$ where $a\in\mathbb R^2$ with $a=(a^1,a^2)$.

A function $f$ is **independent of the second variable** if $\forall y_1,y_2\in\mathbb R, f(x,y_1)=f(x,y_2)$

Then, we have a second question

**2.23(b)**.  Let $A = \{(x,y):x<0, $ or $ x\ge0$ and $y\ne 0\}$.  Find a function $f: A\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $D_2f = 0$, but $f$ is not independent of the second variable.

Clearly, $A\subset\mathbb R^2$.  Any such function we define over $A$, we can extend to all of $\mathbb R^2$, fulfill the conditions of **2.22**, and arrive at a contradiction.  What am I missing here?

Comment: It''s not true that any such function can be extended to all of $\mathbb R^2$, much less in a way that satisfies those conditions. (Why not? Well, that's exactly what the problem asks you to explain.)

Comment: Best I can figure, is that it has to do with implicit continuity.  That is, if we define a jump function, with a constant for $y\lt 0$ and another constant for $y\ge 0$, then the partial derivative is $0$, but $f(x,-1)\ne f(x,1)$.  Is that about right?

Comment: Right, except what you said gives a function that's defined for $y=0$ and is not even continuous there. You meant one constant for $y>0$ and another constant for $y<0$.

Comment: Oops.  Well, it's now clear to me that I was mistaken about being able to extend the function, and that continuity is necessary for $x<0 \text{ and } y=0$ so that the derivative can exist for all of $A$.  Thanks for your help.  If you care to sum up the discussion in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's really going on can be explained in terms of derivatives of one-variable functions. If $I$ is an interval, $f:I\to\mathbb R$ and $f'=0$ then $f$ is constant. But that depends on $I$ being an *interval*. Say $E=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Define $f:E\to\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$, $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$. Then $f'=0$ everywhere on $E$ but $f$ is not constant.

For the actual example asked for in the exercise: Say $f(x,y)=0$ for $x<0$. For $x\ge 0$, let $f(x,y)=x^2$ for $y>0$, $-x^2$ for $y<0$. Then $f$ is differentiable in $A$, $D_2f=0$ but $f$ is not independent of $y$.